# Why does gdb claim "No debugging symbols" when they are present?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, symbols

I have made a chromium binary in debug mode, with debug symbols.
I verified with `nm` that it does indeed have almost 5 million symbols:

```
$ file /snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
/snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[xxHash]=4d9bbabf9743e724, not stripped
$ nm -an /snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome | wc -l
4784374
```

But when I load it into the debugger, gdb tells me that there are no symbols:

```
$ gdb -q /snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
Reading symbols from /snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome...
(No debugging symbols found in /snap/chromium/x9/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome)
```

When I then set a break on a symbol, it does so without complaining:

```
(gdb) break vaCreateSurfaces
Breakpoint 1 at 0x127695a4
(gdb)
```

But then when running, it will not break on it.

Why is gdb so confused about this binary?

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu

**gdb:** 12.1-3ubuntu1

Comment: I believe `file` should also output "`with debug_info`" for a binary with debug info.

Comment: Thanks, there is a difference between "stripped of symbols" and "no debugging symbols" then. I think what happened is that some libraries were built with debug symbols, but the top level was not. Hence, the breakpoint symbol was found.

Comment: On second thought, my comment seems irrelevant. If your `file` utility is older than ~2017, you won't see `with debug_info`, since that was implemented [here](https://github.com/file/file/commit/0e78a704897cba82924665d3a9de4e520b2ce065). Your conclusion does seem correct, however.